# Angular 5 - Function that return another Dynamic Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, angular2-aot

I've created a function that generates a dynamic switch-case function statement.

```
export function generateReducer(initialState, reducerName: ReducerName, adapter: EntityAdapter<any>): (state, initialState) => IState {
  reducerName.plural = reducerName.plural ? reducerName.plural : reducerName.singular + 's';

  return function (state = initialState, action: any): IState {
    switch (action.type) {

        case `[${reducerName.plural} Section] Load Statistics ${reducerName.singular}`:
        case `[${reducerName.plural} Section] Load Details ${reducerName.singular}`:
        case `[${reducerName.plural} Section] Load ${reducerName.plural}`:
            {
                return { ...state, loading: true, loaded: false };
            }
            ...
}
```

and using it like this

export const adapter: EntityAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

```
export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
    loaded: false,
    loading: false,
    selectedId: null
});

export const reducer = generateReducer(initialState, { singular: 'Skill' }, adapter);
```

when running the project with `ng-serve` (not AOT) everything works fine, when trying to build for production using `ng build --prod` I get the following error

> ERROR in src\app\skills\skills.module.ts(46,45): Error during template
>   compile of 'SkillsModule'   Function calls are not supported in
>   decorators but 'generateReducer' was called in 'reducers'
>       'reducers' references 'reducers'
>         'reducers' references 'reducer' at src\app\skills\store\reducers\index.ts(18,13)
>           'reducer' calls 'generateReducer' at src\app\skills\store\reducers\skills.reducer.ts(26,24).

tried to find any way to resolve this, but It seems that I need to provide this to the compiler somehow so he can tell its a compile time function that generates code. any ideas on how to manage with this kind of problem?

EDIT:

added a stackblitz repo to show the error,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reducer-factory-ngrx

download the application, update the package.json devDependencies "@angular/cli": "^1.6.0",
and try to run 'ng build --prod'

Comment: skills.module.ts(46,45) - what is the code on this line please

Comment: StoreModule.forFeature('skillsSection', reducers),

Comment: its the place where I actually use this reducer and add it to the store module.

Comment: which version of ngrx and wich version of angular?

Comment: angular 5.2.6, ngrx latest

Comment: i guess in your place i would build stackblitz code which demonstrates the problem, so it will be easy for ngrx folks  to figure out where is the problem

Comment: added a stackblitz repo.

Comment: i can see that during the "ng serve" run i cannot see any store created in redux devtool...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add at "reducer.ts":

```
  export const reducer = generateReducer(initialState, { singular: 'Skill' }, adapter);

import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

 // register reducer token
 export const reducerToken = new InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<State>>(
   'Registered Reducers'
 );
 Object.assign(reducerToken, reducer);

 export function getReducers() {
   return reducer;
 }
```

and at the app.module.ts:

```
import { reducerToken, getReducers } from './reducer';


@NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducerToken)
 ],
 declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
 providers: [
  {
    provide: reducerToken,
    useFactory: getReducers
  }
 ],
 bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

This way it worked for me...
Hope it  helps

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for. thank you very much!